# Find specific occurrences within a vector in MATLAB, without for-loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, vectorization

I have a problem that seems to be simple but maybe I am missing something. Let us say I have: `vector = [10:1:19];`. I have another vector, `want = [11 16 19];` I simply want a way in which a command will return for me, the indicies at which 11, 16, and 19 occur in vector. In other words, I want to have returned, 2, 7, and 10. What command might do this? I cannot use `find`, (because dimensions do not match), so is there another way?

In reality the length of `vector` and `want` will be long, so a for loop will not do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`intersect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html):

```
[C, i_vector, i_want] = intersect(vector, want)
```

C is the common elements in both vectors. `i_vector` would be the common set indices in `vector` and `i_want` is the matching set indices in `want` vector.

Comment: Thank you! I had NO clue about this. How does MATLAB make this command run extremely fast btw? What is occurring under the hood? Surely no for loops right?

Comment: @Learnaholic well structured for loops can be pretty fast.  Also MatLab is just optimized for matrices.

Comment: @Learnaholic: Also many Matlab built-in functions are optimized and pre-compiled, and if I am not mistaken this sometimes results in more speed.

Comment: @pm89, yes, although I am wondering how one can possibly optimize a for-loop even if pre-compiled...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `ismember`.

To get the element of `vector` present in `want`:

```
vector(ismember(vector,want))
ans =
     11     16    19
```

To get their indexes:

```
find(ismember(vector,want))
ans =
     2     7    10
```

or just:

```
[tf, loc] = ismember(vector,want)
tf =
     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
loc =
     0     1     0     0     0     0     2     0     0     3
```

where tf indicates for each element of `vector` whether it is present in `want`, and `loc` indicate the corresponding indexes in `want`.